# TreeMap with own comparator implementation

Tags: java, dictionary, compare, comparator, treemap

Everyone.

I write a `TreeMap` with an own implementation of method `compare()`.

The aim is to sort the keys of the map in order: entries with less time and less values of bit should be on top. All entries have unique time. I want to choose between objects with bit: `false` - choose objects with less time.

But the following Java code restricts me to add some new entries.

```
private TreeMap<Entry<K>,V>  map = new TreeMap<Entry<K>,V>(new Comparator<Entry<K>>() {

  @Override
  public int compare(Entry<K> entry1, Entry<K> entry2) {

    int time1 = entry1.getTime();        
    int time2 = entry2.getTime();

    boolean bit1 = entry1.isBit();
    boolean bit2 = entry2.isBit();

    if (time1 < time2) {
      if ( (bit1 == false && bit2 == true)
        || (bit1 == false && bit2 == false)
        || (bit1 == true && bit2 == true))
        return -1;
    } else if (time1 > time2) {
      if ( (bit1 == true && bit2 == false)
        || (bit1 == true && bit2 == true)
        || (bit1 == false && bit2 == false))
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
  }

});
```

Can anyone please explain why?

P.s.
I added entry's with keys: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Then I tried to add entry with key 4, and It was not added. 
Key 1, 2 .. - it means i create entry with 3 fields: key, bit(false - default), time(unique value created by counter).
So all entry's im my opninion were unique.

This is entry class:

```
public class Entry<K> {

private K id;
private boolean bit;
private int time;

public Entry(K id, Boolean bit, int time) {

    this.setId(id);
    this.setBit(bit);
    this.setTime(time);

}

public K getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(K id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public boolean isBit() {
    return bit;
}

public void setBit(boolean bit) {
    this.bit = bit;
}

public int getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(int time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public boolean equals(Object o){
    if (this.id == ((Entry)o).getId()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}   
}
```

And in such way I add new entrys:

```
public void put(K key, V value){
    entry = new Entry<K>(key, false, clock++);
    if (map.size() < initialCapacity){
        map.put(entry, value);
    } else {
        if (this.get(key) == null) {
            map.remove(map.firstEntry().getKey());
            map.put(entry, value);
        }
    }           
}

public V get(K key){
    Iterator it = map.keySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()){
        Entry entry = (Entry) it.next();
        if (key.equals(entry.getId())){
            entry.setBit(true);
            return map.get(entry);
        }
    }       
    return null;
}
```

Running code:

```
ClockCacheMaximus<BigInteger, Object> ccm = new ClockCacheMaximus<BigInteger, Object>(3);;
    ccm.put(new BigInteger("1"), "aaa");
    System.out.println("map" + ccm.getAll());
    System.out.println();
    ccm.put(new BigInteger("2"), "bbb");
    System.out.println("map" + ccm.getAll());
    System.out.println();
    ccm.put(new BigInteger("3"), "ccc");
    System.out.println("map" + ccm.getAll());   
    System.out.println();
    ccm.put(new BigInteger("4"), "ddd");
    System.out.println("map" + ccm.getAll());
    System.out.println();
    ccm.put(new BigInteger("5"), "www");
    System.out.println("map" + ccm.getAll());
    System.out.println();
    ccm.put(new BigInteger("4"), "rrr");
    System.out.println("map" + ccm.getAll());
    System.out.println();
    ccm.put(new BigInteger("6"), "rrr");
    System.out.println("map" + ccm.getAll());
    System.out.println();
    ccm.put(new BigInteger("7"), "rrr");
    System.out.println("map" + ccm.getAll());
    System.out.println();
    ccm.put(new BigInteger("8"), "rrr");
    System.out.println("map" + ccm.getAll());
    System.out.println();
    ccm.put(new BigInteger("9"), "rrr");
    System.out.println("map" + ccm.getAll());
```

Result:

Entry: key = 1; bit = false; time = 0; Value = aaa
---put because of norm size: aaa
map[1]

Entry: key = 2; bit = false; time = 1; Value = bbb
---put because of norm size: bbb
map[1, 2]

Entry: key = 3; bit = false; time = 2; Value = ccc
---put because of norm size: ccc
map[1, 2, 3]

Entry: key = 4; bit = false; time = 3; Value = ddd
---put with remove
map[2, 3, 4]

Entry: key = 5; bit = false; time = 4; Value = www
---put with remove
map[3, 4, 5]

Entry: key = 4; bit = false; time = 5; Value = rrr
!object was found
map[3, 4, 5]

Entry: key = 6; bit = false; time = 6; Value = rrr
---put with remove
map[4, 5]

Entry: key = 7; bit = false; time = 7; Value = rrr
---put because of norm size: rrr
map[4, 5]

Entry: key = 8; bit = false; time = 8; Value = rrr
---put because of norm size: rrr
map[4, 5]

Entry: key = 9; bit = false; time = 9; Value = rrr
---put because of norm size: rrr
map[4, 5]

Comment: which were the entries that u could add and ones which u couldnt add ?

Comment: You need to explain more clearly how you wish the `Entry` keys to be ordered. Give some example `Entry` objects and how they would appear in your ordered `Map`.

Comment: The problem is that your definition is that if a < b and b < c its not clear that a < c.  There has to be a simple linear order.

Comment: Your description doesn't make sense. You're using `Entry` objects as keys so what do you mean 'I tried to add entry with key 4'?

Comment: You aren't telling us what the problem is.  "Tried to add entry with key 4" - what's 4?  how does that relate to time1, time2, bits?  give maybe 3 entire entries, all the relevant values, with the third being one that doesn't get entered.  Running code would be best, actually...

Answer (score 2):

TreeMap uses only comparator to check uniqueness.
If you have 2 keys that are equal according to your comparator then one of them will not be added to map. See [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html):

> Note that the ordering maintained by a sorted map (whether or not an
>   explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if the
>   sorted map is to correctly implement the Map interface. (See the
>   Comparable interface or Comparator interface for a precise definition
>   of consistent with equals.) This is so because the Map interface is
>   defined in terms of the equals operation, but a sorted map performs
>   all key comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two
>   keys that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of
>   the sorted map, equal. The behavior of a tree map is well-defined even
>   if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the
>   general contract of the Map interface.

In your opinion keys are unique (and they unique if you check with equals) but `TreeMap` uses only comparator to check uniqueness.